# Нужна помощь со скриптом jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, cookie

Пытаюсь сделать сворачивание блоков с запоминанием, но получилось с косяками... [Вот весь код.](http://jsfiddle.net/nCxPU/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`history.pushState(null, null, url);`
```

используй эту функцию

Comment: эм, и как она поможет?